# How LDAP works in Multisite with separate database?

Tags: multi-sites

I clone dabase 1 and database 2. All users and content are cloned as is. I then use that databases for Multisite. So, our multisite is configured to have one codebase with multiple databases. Do I have to re-authenticate users in a multisite with multiple database? If so, can you tell me why and is there a work around it?